# Regular Expression Password Validator

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a hard time trying to create a right regular expression for the RegularExpressionValidator control that allows password to be checked for the following:
- Is greater than seven characters.
- Contains at least one digit.
- Contains at least one special (non-alphanumeric) character.

Cant seem to find any results out there too. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you will find [this article](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/) helpful. You may try the following expression

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W]).*$
```

and the breakdown:

- `(?=.{8,})` - contains at least 8 characters
- `(?=.*[\d])` - contains at least one digit
- `(?=.*[\W])` - contains at least one special character

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx

Search for "Lookaround processing" which is necessary in these examples. You can also test for a range of values by using `.{4,8}` as in Microsoft's example:

```
^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[\W]).{6,20})
```

Description of above Regular Expression:

```
(           # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)      #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])       #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[\W])        #   must contains at least one special character
              .     #     match anything with previous condition checking
                {7,20}  #        length at least 7 characters and maximum of 20 
)           # End of group
```

"/W" will increase the range of characters that can be used for password and pit can be more safe.

Answer (score 0):

Use for Strong password with Uppercase, Lowercase, Numbers, Symbols & At least 8 Characters.

```
//Code for Validation with regular expression in ASP.Net core.
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,15}$")]
```

Regular expression password validation:

```
@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,15}$"
```